# What is better practice here when it's about to repeat same code multiple times?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, properties, desktop-application

I'm working on wpf application, and there is one part which should be repeated many times, acctually it's about printing documents,
everytime when user clicks print it will be executed, so some informations like PrinterName, Paths etc I'm storing in XML file,
and I'm wondering because that action will be repeated many times **is it better to store it into a global variable**, and set it only once (for example in `App.xaml` file in `Application_Startup` method) and use it any time I need, maybe it is faster than to read it everytime from my XML?

Here is an code example:

**Solution with XML:**

```
//call code below everytime user wants to print document
 Printer printer = new Printer();
 printer.AdressAnswer = Globals.ReadValueFromXML("answeraddress");
 //ReadValueFromXML is my method which is returning value from xml and is defined below




public static string ReadValueFromXML(string nodeName)
 {
    try
    {

     XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("C:\\ApplicationSettings.xml");
     XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
     // Compile a standard XPath expression
     XPathExpression expr;
     expr = nav.Compile(@"/settings/" + nodeName);
     XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);
     // Iterate on the node set
     while (iterator.MoveNext())
     {
        return iterator.Current.Value;
     }
     return string.Empty;
    }
    catch
    {
       //do some error logging here. Leaving for you to do 
       return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**Solution with global variables:**

```
 Printer printer = new Printer();
 printer.AdressAnswer = Globals.PathToFolder;
```

And

```
 Globals.PathToFolder
```

would be previously set in

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
     //Call again ReadValueFromXML method but call it only once and use static variables multiple times 
     Globals.PathToFolder = Globals.ReadValueFromXML("answeraddress");
    }
}
```

And now I'm wondering which solution is better and why?

Comment: When there´s something that *needs* to be done on every request, do it on every request. Otherwise do it only once and store it. But if that really is bad for performance? We can´t know, you may measure this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm just wondering is it better to read values from Global variables on every request or from XML file, maybe from memory (Global variables it is faster) ?

Comment: First: there is no such thing as a global variable in C#, every variale is bound to a class (however not neccessarily to an *instance* of a class). Second: the actual question is not if you want a static or non-static variable, but if you want to read the value on every request, which is obsolete if the value won´t change between requests, isn´t it? So *read* it just once (e.g. on app-startup) and *use* it on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is (at least theoretically) faster not to read the XML values from the file each time. Whether this performance benefit really matters in practice is another question. You need to perform performance testing/measuring to find out.

If the values won't change, you could read them once and store them in memory for the duration of the application's lifetime. It is a tradeoff between memory usage and the execution time of your method really.

But you could for example call the `ReadValueFromXML` method once from a static constructor of the class in which the values are being read and store the valuess in some static class that you then use in your "real" print method.

Comment: can you edit your answer little bit with example of how that might look, lets say there is allready  public static class Globals and there is some property called whatever you want, and let's see how that should look in practice, and true it wont be changed once it's loaded, it is acctually printer name and a path to folder where documents are :)

Comment: What do you mean? You read the values like before in the static method and set the properties of Globals. In the "print" method, you don't read these values from the file but from the properties of Globals.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are looking for App.config and [Appsetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx)

This way you can store your file path  in app.config in your startup project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
         <startup>
             <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
          </startup>
          <appSettings>
              <add key="PathToFolder" value="C:\\ApplicationSettings.xml" />
          </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

And acces it in your code like this

```
string pathToFolder =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PathToFolder") ;
```